# Show Locations ONLY if a custom field has a value in WP Store Locator?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the entires JUST IF a special variable is filled out.
For example: Just show the location if it has a phone number. Is that possible?

I am wondering if the functions.php is the correct place for this?! Because this has to be checked for each entry, or not?

I use the function custom_listing_template() and I want to create an if query around the

Entries. So that they just show if a - for example - Phone number exists.